# Python How to throw an exception if Operating System starts to shutdown/restart/etc

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, backup, shutdown

As an example:

My python script is running

And sometimes I forgot my script is running then I accidentally shut down my computer

Is there anyways to let my script quickly throw an exception and perform some other movements before system get shutdown?

Comment: In general, no.  Some OS will send a shutdown notification message, but you will only have a limited time to perform a managed shutdown of your app before the OS kills it.  Since hardware/power fail can happen at any time, it's best if you can design your system to safely survive unplanned death.